# append value get null in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with javascipt. I am going to show recent image above the browe image button as preview image.

Here, There are 4 question and when I browse image of that for question it show the preview image. When I click on **Add more** button it append another question.

When,I browse image for that quetion it gives an error that it return **null**.

Here, this is my javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var n = 5;
        var i = 2;
        var j = 10;
        var k = 2;
        
        $('.addmore').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var div = $('#appendData');
            var html  = '';
            html  += '';
            html  += '<div class="formPartd">';
            html  += '<div class="formPartd_left">';
            html  += '<div class="upload-img">';
            html  += '<label><?php __d('statictext', 'Upload Image', false); ?>'+n+'</label>';
            html  += '<span>';
            html  += '<?php if($langlist[$_SESSION['Config']['language']]=='Spanish'){ ?>';
            html  += '<img id="thumbnil'+j+'" src="<?php echo $this->webroot?>images/no_status_image_sp.jpg" class="uploadimg" alt="">';
            html  += '<?php }else{ ?>';
            html  += '<img id="thumbnil'+j+'" src="<?php echo $this->webroot?>images/no-pollimg.jpg" class="uploadimg" alt="">';
            html  += '<?php } ?>';
            html  += '<?php if($langlist[$_SESSION["Config"]["language"]]=="Spanish"){ $browseClass = "browse-btn02";}else{ $browseClass = "browse-btn"; } ?>';
            html  += '<input type="file" class="<?php echo $browseClass;?> validate[required]" onchange="showMyImage1(this,\'thumbnail'+j+'\')" name="data[question1][question_image'+n+']" id="" />';
             html  += '</span>';
            html  += '<div class="clear10"></div>';
            html  += '</div>';
            html  += '<div class="fildtpart3 pos">';
            html  += '<label><?php __d('statictext', 'Answer', false); ?>'+n+'</label>';
            html  += '<span><input name="data[question_ans1][answer'+n+']" type="text" class="validate[required]" id="" value=""></span>';
            html  += '<div class="clear10"></div>';
            html  += '</div>';
            html  += '</div>';
            div.append(html);  
            i++;j++;n++;
            $(document).trigger('updated');

        });
    });

function showMyImage1(fileInput,id) {
    var files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;
        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }
      
        //alert(id);
        var img = document.getElementById(id);
        //alert(img);
        img.file = file;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
         //alert(aImg);
            return function(e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="formPartd_left">
                        <div class="upload-img">
                            <label>Upload Image 3</label>
                            <span><img id="thumbnil3" src="<images/no_status_image_sp.jpg" class="uploadimg" alt="">
<input type="file" class="browse-btn02 validate[required]" onchange="showMyImage1(this,'thumbnil3')" name="data[question1][question_image3]" id="profile_image" />
                                    </span>
                            <div class="clear10"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fildtpart3 pos">
                            <label>Answer3</label>
                            <span><input name="data[question_ans1][answer3]" type="text" class="validate[required]" id="" value=""></span>
                            <div class="clear10"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="fildtpart2" style="float:right">
               <a href="" type="button " class="csv_button addmore " style="float:right;background:#5a9325">Add More
               </a>
            </div>
```

When I click on append browse button it gives an error like 
`img is null
img.file = file;` but it works fine for given html("not append").

So, How can I resolve this eror?

Comment: can u console.log(fileInput) ... in first line of showMyImage1  and what u get ... just let me know..

Comment: @JaiminMosLake it return as `<input id="form-validation-field-1" class="browse-btn validate[required]" type="file" name="data[question1][question_image5]" onchange="showMyImage1(this,'thumbnail10')">`

Comment: compare with ... the working one .... is it same or different ...?

Comment: And what is the difference between those two..?

Comment: @JaiminMosLake both are the same but id change.

Comment: @JaiminMosLake i have an error at this line `var img = document.getElementById(id);`

Comment: try   $("#"+id)    instead of var img = document.getElementById(id);